# Same Image Target with different name confuses vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am creating a app in which the spellings will be checked through vuforia.
Here the alphabets are the image targets. So each alphabet will be tracked and their order will be checked.
For example:
for the word "RABBIT" each alphabets will be tracked.

The issue is how to detect the second "B"?
I have added the image of "B" twice with different name in vuforia dataset: "B" and "B1"
when I track the spelling sometimes vuforia gets confuse in "B" and "B1" as the image is same and shows wrong result for correct spelling.

how can I differentiate them with same image in unity?

I have tried to give different names, size.
Anyone have an idea how to make it possible in unity?

Answer (score 1):

Identical targets, even with different names, are not officially supported by Vuforia (see the official answer in the Unity forum here https://forum.unity.com/threads/detect-multiple-occurrences-of-the-same-image-target.511955/). Personally I found that the trick of adding the target twice cannot be relied upon, sometimes works, sometimes not.

Also, using ImageTargets to track letters might not work robustly for most letters as the target appearance is not being feature rich (see here https://library.vuforia.com/objects/best-practices-designing-and-developing-image-based-targets).